# How can I add all my users to a Role in Parse.com?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, roles

I'm having a class UserRatings for user to rate different places. Currently the class has a Public Read and Write ACL. I need to add all my users to a new role so that I can change the public read and write to my new role. How can I add all my users to this role? Also, how can I update the role when a new user is signed up?

I've used the following code to add all my existing users to the class.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    allUsers=objects;
    NSLog(@"%@",allUsers);
}];


PFACL *roleACL = [PFACL ACL];
PFRole *role = [PFRole roleWithName:@"UserRatingsRole" acl:roleACL];
for (PFUser *user in allUsers) {
    [role.users addObject:user];
}
[role saveInBackground];
```

I've not given any child roles. Is that an issue? When I check my Parse Roles, I can't find any users listed in my role. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query for the Role object on the server, then continue as you already have.

Try this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    allUsers=objects;
NSLog(@"%@",allUsers);
}];

PFQuery *queryRole = [PFRole query];
[queryRole whereKey:@"UserRatingsRole" equalTo:roleName];
[queryRole getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    PFRole *role = (PFRole *)object;
    for (var i = 0; i < allUsers.length; i++) {
       role.getUsers().add(allUsers[i]);
    }
    role.save();
}];
```

You can also check out the answer here: https://parse.com/questions/add-users-to-role